# Can we have all our site tweets fall under the #b3d hashtag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-promotion

For those who don't know, [*every* StackExchange site gets an automated twitter account](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/). All these basically do is

> …publish the most interesting content on each Stack Exchange site every
>   three hours — without ever repeating themselves.

Ours is [@StackBlender](https://twitter.com/stackblender) and it is starting to attract some attention.

Blender already has a massive following on twitter under the [#b3d](https://twitter.com/search/realtime?q=#b3d) hashtag which was accepted as [the standard](http://www.blendernation.com/2011/02/11/b3d-twitter-hashtag/) ~3 years ago and twitter is a community we haven't really reached out to yet.

Currently, the tags that are added to the tweets are next to useless as they are very vague and don't have any scope per se. Tags like [#pythonapi](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23pythonapi&src=hash) and [#nodes](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23nodes&src=hash) to name a few. Can we dismiss appending those tags and just use one tag for all our site content?

The #b3d hashtag is *very* active so I don't think we will be spamming anyone who follows it and this might help give our site a boost in visits etc.. One we could use [at the moment](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40377/blender).

<sup>* credits to [zeffii](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8888?m=10200607#10200607) for the idea.</sup>

Comment: Yes! I really like this idea. I'm on twitter a lot and the only blender related tag I ever visit/tweet on is #b3d. In my opinion, Twitter would be one of the best sites for promoting Blender.SE posts, as tweets are obviously short, quick messages (and won't really spam twitarians).

Comment: I like this idea. Also, this site is doing very well from what I can see. 600 visits per day is actually pretty good for not even two months old.

Comment: @Luke yeah, might be expecting too much, but we were at 1k some days ago. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is done - all new tweets [here](https://twitter.com/stackblender) will include the tag #b3d *and no other tags whatsoever*.

Comment: Maybe we can use a minimum up-vote count before getting tweeted, this might minimize attention to questions that are beyond the scope of B.SE.